# Logging pf messages under OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, logging, syslog

I'm trying to get pf working under Mountain Lion.  Since it appears that Apple neglected to include pflogd, we have to make our own like:

```
/sbin/ifconfig pflog0 create
/usr/sbin/tcpdump -lnettti pflog0 | /usr/bin/logger -t pf
```

This dumps messages into system.log, but I'm trying to find a way to sort them out into their own.  I was able to figure this out with ipfw, but ipfw left nice logs like:

```
Mar  5 11:34:44 flamingo kernel[0] <Debug>: ipfw: 65534 Deny ICMP:3.10 192.168.4.233 192.168.92.60 in via en0
```

For pf, I'm getting logs like:

```
Mar  5 11:57:50 flamingo.mydomain.com pf[51938]: 00:00:00.000000 rule 1/8(ip-option): pass in on en0: 172.24.32.41 > 224.0.0.1: igmp query v2
```

With OSXes 'logger', I can use -p to set a facility, but then the logs quietly vanish.  I found references to using 'syslog -s -k facility whatever', but when I pipe my tcpdump into syslog, the process dies after a few seconds or minutes.

How can I A) find out how to keep syslog running, or B) either set or predict what I could filter the results from logger in asl.conf?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one ingredient to get logging.

This worked for me:

```
root# touch /var/log/pffirewall.log` to create the log file.
```

Then, add the following line to `/etc/syslog.conf`:

```
local2.* /var/log/pffirewall.log
```

Now your logger process output will show up in `/var/log/pffirewall.log`. Apparently logger is still tied to the old syslog facility and `/etc/syslog.conf`.